# How to git fetch an android security patch

Tags: android, git

I am working on a custom android rom and everything's working. Now I need to apply android security patches (source's security patch level is from December 2017) and I am missing some basic knowledge.

Say I want to apply this: https://android.googlesource.com/pla...011bcd751fcbb5

From what I understand, I need to git cherry-pick the commit, using a command line like what can be found in the googlesource review page. For exemple:

```
git fetch https://android.googlesource.com/pla...rameworks/base refs/changes/24/527324/1 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

How do I find the "refs/changes..." part for any given security patch in the bulletins?

I have tried several approaches to no avail. Also searched all over google, XDA and here at StackOverflow and couldn't find any specific answer to my "problem".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: quick googling found me this cmd: `git ls-remote`. Doing that gives you a bunch of commit hashes and the corresponding **refs/.../...**

Comment: If you are just looking for the manual process, you can find download button on the review page which will give you the command

Comment: Thanks. I will try that command (I have googled a lot and did not find that, sure I need to improve that too). And regarding the download yeah, I find the button and it gives you the proper git fetch commands in the review page, but security patches are not in the review and I haven't been able to find them...

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727836/how-do-i-manually-update-my-custom-roms-security-patches-using-git-cherry-pick