# How do I manually update my custom rom's security patches using 'git cherry-pick'?

Tags: android, git

I made a custom rom for my device using Resurrection Remix Nougat. However, the security patch of the rom is December 5, 2017. I've found a guide that gives instructions (https://thealaskalinuxuser.wordpress.com/2016/08/29/how-to-manually-update-your-custom-rom-source-code-with-security-updates/) but it says to manually edit the files, even though there are commit codes on the pages (ex: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4afa0352d6c1046f9e9b67fbf0011bcd751fcbb5)

Is there a way to add these commits using 'git cherry-pick' or something else without manually editing the files?

I have tried the following (with this example: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4afa0352d6c1046f9e9b67fbf0011bcd751fcbb5)

1. go to frameworks/base using 'cd frameworks/base'
2. 'git fetch https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base'
3. 'git cherry-pick 4afa0352d6c1046f9e9b67fbf0011bcd751fcbb5

After running the chery-pick command, I get this:

fatal: bad object 4afa0352d6c1046f9e9b67fbf0011bcd751fcbb5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
git fetch https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base  4afa0352d6c1046f9e9b67fbf0011bcd751fcbb5 --depth 2
git cherry-pick 4afa0352d6c1046f9e9b67fbf0011bcd751fcbb5
```

And here's another method. Press the button `diff` on the page of https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4afa0352d6c1046f9e9b67fbf0011bcd751fcbb5, and the diff/patch of the commit is displayed, which starts with the line

```
diff --git a/core/java/android/net/Uri.java b/core/java/android/net/Uri.java
```

You can copy and paste the diff into a local file, `foo.diff` for example, and run

```
git apply foo.diff
```

Comment: I tried the first way and I got this:

(Not currently on any branch.
You are currently cherry-picking commit 4afa0352d6c.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git reset')

What does this mean and what can I do?

Comment: @TomShrew “not currently on any branches” means detached HEAD. “Nothing to commit” means the patch has already been applied before and it can’t be applied again.

Comment: Alright. So I have to manually check if the patch is applied or not?

Answer (score 0):

'go to frameworks/base using 'cd frameworks/base'

'git fetch https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base' -A

'git cherry-pick 4afa0352d6c1046f9e9b67fbf0011bcd751fcbb5